# Removed Plugin still has active keybindings from view/ files

Tags: key-bindings, plugin-system, plugin-vim-latex

I installed the plugin `vimtex`.
Then I installed the plugin `tex-vim` (aka Latex suite).
The compilation keybinding (`<Leader>ll`) from `vimtex` stopped working, since `tex-vim` takes over it.
So I removed `tex-vim` from my list of Plugs and ran `:PlugClean` (I use `vim-plug` as my plugin manager).
Now when I press `<Leader>ll` it says "Unknown function Tex_RunLatex", meaning that the keybinding for the `tex-vim` command is still present even after I removed `tex-vim`.
By running `:verbose map \ll` I can see that the keybinding is set in a file from the `~/.local/share/nvim/view/` directory. Deleting said file does not solve anything: vim simply creates another one when I restart vim.

What to do to stop `tex-vim` overwriting my keybindings from the grave, and, if possible, how to stop it from overwriting `vimtex` keybinding while using both plugins?

Comment: disable whatever plugin you are using that creates a session or view. Then try again (and read `:h 'sessionoptions'` and remove the `options` value)

Comment: Or delete the view files, it remove whatever is automatically loading the views

Comment: @D.BenKnoble As I said, I did remove the view files but it did nothing...

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I am not sure what you mean: running `:set sessionoptions` gives `sessionoptions=blank,buffers,curdir,folds,help,tabpages,winsize`. Do you want be to delete it all?

Comment: according to your sessionoptions, it shouldn't save options and mappings. Are you sure that is correct, because it would mean you do not have that problem. The simplest solution is to quit nvim, remove all session and view files and start over again. Also are you sure, you need a session/view management plugin?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I found a plugin that saved my session state, and removing it solved my problem! I used to use it only to save my folds, but that can be accomplished in other ways. Thank you!

Comment: @Soap Please post an answer with your findings! It might help others in the same situation that get to your question while searching for a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with the "restore-view" plugin.
Disabling it solved the issue.

I was only using it for saving my folds. That can be achieved my using `:mkview` and `:loadview`.